# Issue with mysql join query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am having a problem with a mysql query. I want to have multilevel child ids of a parent. So if the parent id is 18 then I want to have child ids of 18 and if there is another level of any child then I want them as well based on type id

My Table structure is like below -- pages Table

```
id      title             parent_id      type_id

18      About Us          0              4
19      Child 1           18             6
20      child 2           18             7
21      child 3           18             1
22      sub child 1       21             14
23      sub child 2       21             14
24      sub child 3       21             15
```

Second Table -- page_types

```
id          typetitle

6           one column
7           two column
14          slider
```

My desired output should be

```
id      title             parent_id      type_id        typetitle

19      Child 1           18             6              one column
20      child 2           18             7              two column
22      sub child 1       21             14             slider
23      sub child 2       21             14             slider
```

My query is

```
SELECT 
   p.id AS childid,
   p.title AS ptitle,
   pt.typetitle as page_type_title
   FROM pages AS p,page_types as pt
   where p.type_id in (6,7,14) and p.parent_id=18 and p.type_id = pt.id
```

But I am getting only 2 rows( 19 and 20) but not 22 and 23.

Comment: You need to remove : p.parent_id=18

Comment: I can't as I need the parent id 18 and all the child of 21 but depending on the type id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want the leafs of the tree but not the intermediate nodes.  Try doing this:

```
SELECT p.id AS childid, p.title as ptitle, pt.typetitle as page_type_title
FROM pages p join
     page_types pt
     ON p.type_id = pt.id
WHERE p.type_id in (6, 7, 14) and
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM pages p2 WHERE p2.parent_id = p.id);
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ca33b9/1) is a SQL Fiddle showing the query in action.

Comment: Thanks Gordon but I am getting all the ids now no matter which child page I am on. Isn't there any way to get the ids 19,20,22 and 23.

Comment: @Raj . . . That is what this query returns.  Look at the SQL Fiddle.

Comment: When I run sql it displays nothing in the fiddle..Also I tried it in my local phpmyadmin but it is same as before.Might be something is wrong from my end.

Comment: @Raj . . . When I run the code in SQL Fiddle, it definitely returns what you want.  I do notice that SQL Fiddle did not include the code on the right-hand side before.  This seems to happen occasionally.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. The query works great. Thanks. Just wondering if there is any way to pass the parent id 18 and then it will find and get me 19 20 22 23 only.

Comment: @Raj . . . MySQL doesn't support recursive queries or hierarchical queries.  To do what you really seem to want with your data structure would require a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

I thinks this is what you search about it :

```
SELECT * FROM pages AS p INNER JOIN types AS t ON p.type_id = t.id WHERE p.type_id in (6,7,14) and p.parent_id <> 0
```